# How to restricted component based on user roles? Angular

Tags: angular, authentication

When user Login it will check the user roles.
User has assigned specific role for each dashboard.
if he assigned the roles only then he can access otherwise he can't.
Help me to find the solutions.
Thanks
Example:
he can redirect on Admin Dashboard or User Dashboard, or Client Dashboard,

AppRouting.component.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: "/login",
    pathMatch: "full"
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: {
      roles: [
        //View.all,
      ]
    },

    component: LayoutsComponent, loadChildren: () => import('./coreengine/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m=> m.DashboardModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'advanced', component: LayoutsComponent, loadChildren: () => import('./coreengine/advancemode/advancemode.module').then(m=> m.AdvancemodeModule)
  },
];
```

User.service.ts

```
//check user Logged in true and false
   isUserLoggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
   userLogin(data:any): Observable<any>{
      return this.http.get(this.baseURL+'/userLoginId?loginId='+data.username+'&password='+data.password).pipe(map(res => res));
   }
```

Auth.guard.ts

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem('userId')){
      return true;
    }else{
      this.router.navigate(['/login'],{relativeTo : this.route});
    }  
    return this.loginService.isUserLoggedIn;
```

When user Login it will check the user roles.
User has assigned specific role for each dashboard.
if he assigned the roles only then he can access otherwise he can't.
Help me to find the solutions.
Thanks
Example:
he can redirect on Admin Dashboard or User Dashboard, or Client Dashboard,

Answer (score 0):

You could create one more guard, that will check the intersection between your user roles and roles attached to the route. Be aware, that depending on your router configuration you may need to refactor routes and place AuthGuard at the top level of the configuration and RolesGuard at the nested ones, which will guarantee that AuthGuard will be triggered first. Here is a short example of this guard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from '../UserServise';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private userSerive: UserService) {}
  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    // roles attached at the router config;
    const { allowedRouteRoles } = next.data.roles;
    // user roles;
    const { roles: userRoles } = this.userSerive.user;
    // intersection
    return userRoles.some((role) => allowedRouteRoles.includes(role));
  }
}
```